# How to get array deleted and added items?

Tags: c#

I have an array like:

```
var list1 = string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
```

then I change it to :

```
var list2 = string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "6" ,"9"};
```

I try by `list1.Except(list2);` but this only return different items
How can I find out which item is deleted and which item is added to array.

Comment: @Artemix I know , this is just an example.

Comment: Nothing was added or deleted. You created a new array and now you want to compare the two. What *do* you want to find? Except doesn't return the differences, it returns the "deleted" items - ie those that exist in list1 but not list2. Reverse the arguments and you will get the "added" ones

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just flip the `Except`:

```
var list1 = new string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
var list2 = new string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "6" ,"9"};

var added   = list2.Except(list1);
var deleted = list1.Except(list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SETS (i.e.: HashSet)

It contains members like:

- Intesections
- Unions
- Symetric Except
- Except
- IsSubsetOf
- IsSuperSetOf
- Overlaps
  etc...